# Agregate Different String Columns on Pandas - List of Unique Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a problem to get the **unique values** of two different columns **ordered A-Z** and **ignoring `nan` values**.
I was trying to create an ordered list of unique values, then remove the brackets, but I struggle.
Can someone please help me on this?

#### Columns to order:

- `df['A']`
- `df['B']`

Thanks in advance.

##### Sample Data

```py
import pandas as pd
dict = {'A': ['1','2','8','4',nan],
        'B': ['6','2','3','9','10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

##### Desired Output

|  | A | B | expected_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 6 | 1, 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 3 | 3, 8 |
| 3 | 4 | 9 | 4, 9 |
| 4 | nan | 10 | 10 |

##### Solution given by user @somedude and @rawson

```py
df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.drop_duplicates().dropna()), axis=1)
```

##### Solution given by @mozway

```py
df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().unique()), axis=1)
```

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)` ?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information: Which column do you want to order? What have you tried so far? Why do you want to order numeric series by A-Z? Which brackets do you need to remove?

Comment: @Andre does SomeDude's comment address your question? If not, why?

Comment: Adding to the answer by @SomeDude to include `drop_duplicates`: `df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.drop_duplicates().dropna()), axis=1)`

Comment: The answer given by SomeDude doen not work 100%.   But with the contribution of @Rawson it WORKED 100%.

Comment: @mozway The answer with improvement worked 100%

Comment: OK, then `', '.join(x.dropna().unique())` might be more efficient

Comment: @mozway thanks!  Your solution is in the post!